# Solve PDE: $u_x +u_y =u^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need help this: Solve the following initial value problem (quasilinear problem)

$u_x + u_y= u^2$, $u(x,0) =h(x)$

Here what I did: The initial curve $\Gamma:<x=s, y=0, z=h(s)>$ and the characteristic equations: $dx/dt = 1$, $dy/dt = 1$ and $dz/dt =u^2 =z^2$. So I get $x = t + s$, $y = t$ and $z=u^2t + h(s)$. Then solution is $u=u^2y + h(x-y)$
I am not sure about this answer.
Please advise. Thanks

Comment: The point is that along the characteristics, $\frac{du}{dt}=u^2$. Explicitly, $\frac{d}{dt} u(x_0+t,t)=u(x_0+t,t)^2$ for any $x_0$. But the solution to $\frac{du}{dt}=u^2$ does not look like what you just said.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equations are given by:

$$dx/1=dy/1=du/u^2.$$

From the first equality, we obtain $x-y=c_1$. From the second equality, we obtain $-c_2+y=-1/u \implies u= \frac{1}{c_2-y}=\frac{1}{F(c_1)-y}=\frac{1}{F(x-y)-y}.$

From $u(x,0)=h(x)$ we obtain $F(x)=1/h(x)$, hence

$$u = \frac{h(x-y)}{1-yh(x-y)}$$

Comment: how can you get "from $u(x,0)=h(x)$ we obtain $F(x)=1/h(x)$"?

Comment: @Vui Tinh, directly above that line it says $u(x,y) = \frac 1{F(x-y)-y}$. So let $y = 0$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have solved the ODE $z'(t)=z^2(t)$ incorrectly. One can solve this ODE e.g. via separation of variables to get

$$z(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{h(s)}-t}.$$

Now we have $x=t+s=y+s$ hence $s=x-y$. Thus we have the solution

$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{h(x-y)}-y}.$$